Is there a way of working out systemd dependencies for a service you're creating?
This is possibly a silly question but other than a few common options / educated guesses / knowing the entire kernel/systemd inside-out is there some way of determining what dependencies and in what order a piece of code should have defined when making it a systemd service?
For example; I have a piece of code that uses the serial port, uinput, and sockets - I've found that I need to include this in the service:
[Unit]
BindsTo=dev-serial0.device
After=dev-serial0.device

So that the serial port is available to it when it starts - But I can't for example find if there's a service or other dependency for uinput that I might need to include.
So - is there a list of services/names somewhere or a command you can run that shows what a particular executable is depending on?

No, that would need knowledge of what the executable does at runtime, and since your computer is a universal one, that would require analyzing all possible code paths.

It would not be wildly optimistic to think a tool could analyse code or an executable and pull out includes or system calls and spit out a list of dependencies, there's plenty of very advanced code analysis tools and debuggers out there.

Uff, as someone working with static analyzers, you're massively overestimating what they can do for dynamically linked programs (which describes most daemons that interact with others); how should a static analyzer know what you get from other services at runtime? Which dbus interfaces you query? Which ports you connect to if they are written in config files instead of hardcoded in the code? That's all logically impossible to do with a code analysis. Debugging is irrelevant, for that you need to, again, observe the runtime behaviour.

I think you're making grand assumptions about the complexity of my code here - its a small C program that uses a few basic system features - the serial port, listening on a socket, and uinput - and I'm just trying to find out why it works as a standalone executable but not reliably when called as a systemd service. My assumption is it's a dependency or order of execution in the boot chain. Just being able to find a list of systemd things (units? services?) with a description of what they do / what features they provide would be a start, or as I say working backwards from #include <xyz>

for that kind of program, why would you need any tooling? that makes no sense. And as said, you cannot follow from code to what services you need. These are orthogonal things. You don't #include, say, a HTTP server, a network interface, or an input device.

Is it so silly to imagine that you may infer for example that using sockets might require some network service dependency or using uinput might require a uinput service or something to be loaded - I don't feel like I'm being wildly unreasonable here in trying to derive dependencies from fairly basic information be it programmatically or just by referring to some as-yet undiscovered documentation. I'm not expecting a magic tool the decompile my code and craft a systemd unit entry for me, just trying to work out how/where I'm supposed to find this information.

but you asked a technical question, I gave my technical expertise, and now you try to argue that I must be wrong. How's that reasonable? I just tell you that the tool you want to sadly can't exist, for reasons I explain above.

I'm not saying you're wrong - I'm saying you're not answering the actual question, you're answering what you imagine I asked. I am asking how to determine by whatever means what should go into a given systemd service file, as almost all the examples and tutorials online just pluck things out of thin air or assume knowledge. I'm specifically asking where that knowledge is or how it's derived.


Is there a way of working out systemd dependencies

yes a web search and read any article about systemd dependency tree will give better explanations than I could write here, for example https://www.baeldung.com/linux/systemd-execution-tree
Commands you would use that answers that question:

systemd-analyze and see man systemd-analyze

systemd-analyze blame
systemd-analyze critical-chain
systemd-analyze dump
systemd-analyze plot
systemd-analyze dot
systemd-analyze unit-paths


systemctl list-dependencies


is there a list of services/names somewhere or a command you can run that shows what a particular executable is depending on?

yes, what I just mentioned above will provide that information

is there some way of determining what dependencies and in what order a piece of code should have defined

only you (the author) would know (should know) what dependencies are required for your piece of code which I assume you mean service that you are creating which will then run some piece of code specified by ExecStart=.  As for having to know what order your piece of code should have [service dependencies] defined that is systemd's job you don't need to worry about that all gets inherently worked out with all the Before= and After= assignments in every service file which then makes up the entire systemd dependency tree.  You don't need to necessarily know the entire tree but to look at it you can as I described above.  All you need to know is what your service and piece of code specifically requires as a dependency (i.e. already running) which would be specified with a After= statement in your service file.
systemd Before and After declarations

Perhaps I wasn't clear - I know what system calls my code makes and how dependencies work, but I want to know where I find out if those calls would need a dependency defined or if they are just inherently present in the OS from the moment of booting. Saying systemd's tools can tell me what dependencies there are is not helpful as I assume it is working that out by parsing the contents of the service/unit files, so if I don't know what should be in my file in the first place running systemd-analyze on it is not going to tell me what's missing?

For system calls your code makes you would look into the origins of those system calls and what [services] may provide those calls, in which case you would look then through the systemd tree.  But without knowing what syscalls you are talking about I don't know what else to say.  syscalls are system functions so from that perspective I would suspect simply After=basic.target as well as definitely by multi-user.target.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460252/does-all-system-calls-execute-in-kernel-mode   the distinction between system calls and library calls has been blurred, as things that are/were traditionally implemented... 

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html   I would start by identifying what syscalls you are dealing with, and then if they are actually syscalls for the given kernel/distro you are running; I mean google AI result I think gives a decent response on linux system calls dependency list : A Linux system call dependency list would generally not exist in a strict sense as most system calls function independently but I think the stackoverflow link really identifies the problem as first make sure it is still a real syscall you are dealing with

got any good links to where I could look up those [services] ?

for uinput that you mentioned (that I just recognized) - https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/uinput.html.  So as I would interpret it in regards to a systemd service it would be After=basic.target.  If your perspective is what stuff is a dependency to the syscall uinput now you're in the kernel at a level below where systemd is being or (not yet) defined or loaded; systemd is started by the kernel.

other thing is Requires= for a systemd .service, and having a .device listed like you did with After=dev-serial0.device (as opposed to a .target that I am used to seeing) I don't know if is acceptable; you have to look into the systemd administrators guide.
